# Tennis-Refactoring-Kata through OOP

Tags: java, object-oriented, state-machine

I was trying to solve [Tennis-Refactoring-Kata](https://github.com/emilybache/Tennis-Refactoring-Kata). This seems quite hard at startup but, through use os OOP it can be deeply refactoring using just a single `if`.

My first understanding was about the fact that `TennisGame` (the main class) has a `Score`. Or at least should have one.

Furthermore score possibilities are just twenty (*Love-All*, *Fifteen-All* and so on...) and each one leads further `Score`s based on who is the last player who scores a point (e.g.: *Love-All* leads to *Fifteen-Love* if last point has been scored by first player, *Love-Fifteen* otherwise). From this observation I wrote 20 classes like this:

```
public class LoveAll implements IScore {

    public IScore Player1Scored() {
        return new FifteenLove();
    }

    public IScore Player2Scored() {
        return new LoveFifteen();
    }

    public String Label() {
        return "Love-All";
    }
}
```

This should seems a loss of time but this is not bad as it seems since each class is simple and concise. This give me the possibilities to write a `TennisGame4` like this:

```
public class TennisGame4 implements TennisGame {    
    private IScore score = null; // Composition here - TennisGame has a Score
    private String player1Name;
    private String player2Name;

    public TennisGame4(String player1Name, String player2Name) {
        this.player1Name = player1Name;
        this.player2Name = player2Name;
        score = new LoveAll();
    }

    public void wonPoint(String playerName) {
        if (playerName.equals("player1"))
            score = score.Player1Scored();
        else 
            score = score.Player2Scored();
    }

    public String getScore() {
        return score.Label();
    }
}
```

Just a single `if` to distinguish who is the last player who score a point.
What do you think about this solution? Does this solution respect the kata constraint?

Consider that:

- Code surely can be enhanced (Player should be an object too);
- To stay in the Kata I have do everything in 90 minutes or so;

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense to have a class for each possible score combination. Why not a Score class with properties that is/are the score(s)?

Comment: What you've implemented is actually a finite state machine, albeit in a weird and verbose way. Each "score" correspond to a state. "Player1 scores" and "player2 scores" are the two events causing state transition. From my experience, state machine is often better expressed as plain data(e.g. strings or enum) than type hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, there are only a limited possibilities for a `Score`, which I would call `GameScore` to be more precise. This calls for an enum.

```
public enum GameScore {
    S0000(0, 0), S1500(15, 0), S3000(30, 0), ...;

    private static final GameScore[] SWIN = { S1500, ... };
    private static final GameScore[] RWIN = { S0015, ... };
    private static final String[] NAME = { "Love-All", ... };

    ...

    public GameScore serverWins() {
        return SWIN[ordinal()];
    }

    public GameScore returnerWins() {
        return RWIN[ordinal()];
    }

    public String getDisplayText() {
        return NAME[ordinal()];
    }
}
```

That's all. All in one class, ready for testing.

By the way, in Java all method names start with a lowercase letter, not an uppercase. (That would be C# or Ada.)

Using an `enum` and predefined string literals has the benefit of generating zero memory allocations at runtime.